# How to extend CheckboxInput for a list of checkboxes

Tags: python, flask, wtforms, flask-wtforms

I am currently using a MultiCheckboxField like this:

```
class MultiCheckboxField(SelectMultipleField):
    """
    A multiple-select, except displays a list of checkboxes.

    Iterating the field will produce subfields, allowing custom rendering of
    the enclosed checkbox fields.
    """

    widget = widgets.ListWidget(prefix_label=False)
    option_widget = widgets.CheckboxInput()
```

to generate a list of checkboxes.  I would like to extend this list in such a way as to allow some of the list entries to have an associated TextInput field.  When the box is checked, the corresponding text input is required.

I am new to Flask and WTForms, and I am having some trouble trying to figure out just how to attack the problem.  I would be grateful for any suggestions that might provide some kind of direction.

Answer (score 0):

See the FieldList and FormField with custom widgets
http://wtforms.readthedocs.org/en/latest/fields.html#field-enclosures

Answer (score 0):

You can use a custom validator like this:

```
class RequiredIfChoice(validators.DataRequired):
    # a validator which makes a field required if
    # another field is set and has a truthy value

    def __init__(self, other_field_name, desired_choice, *args, **kwargs):
        self.other_field_name = other_field_name
        self.desired_choice = desired_choice
        super(RequiredIfChoice, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def __call__(self, form, field):
        other_field = form._fields.get(self.other_field_name)
        if other_field is None:
            raise Exception('no field named "%s" in form' % self.other_field_name)
        for value, label, checked in other_field.iter_choices():
            if label == self.desired_choice and checked:
                super(RequiredIfChoice, self).__call__(form, field)
```

and in your form:

```
class MyForm(Form):
    """
    Your form.
    """
    multi = MultiCheckboxField('Multibox', choices=[(1, 'First'), (2, 'Second')], coerce=int)
    multitext = StringField('SubText', [RequiredIfChoice('multi', 'Second')])
```

For a slightly similar question look at [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8464478/157216).