# CSS for Flask wtforms

Tags: python, css, flask, wtforms, flask-wtforms

I have a the following code for a Form that I have in my Flask application using Wtforms. I use FieldList to use two fields for one part.

```
class A(Form)
        additional = FieldList(FormField(Additional), 'Additional', min_entries=1)
        submit = SubmitField('Submit')

class Additional(Form):
        choices = [('Funding Mechanism', 'Funding Mechanism'), ('Study Section Name', 'Study Section Name')]
        critera = SelectField('Additional Criteria', choices=choices)
        input = StringField()
```

The template uses wtf.quick_form:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% import "bootstrap/wtf.html" as wtf %}

{% block title %}Grants - Find Grant{% endblock %}

{% block page_content %}
<div class="page-header">
    <h1>Specify</h1>
</div>
<div class="col-md-4">
    {{ wtf.quick_form(form) }}
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

Currently the forms render in a squished and overlapping way like so: [image]

How can I change the code so that it is formated in one line like below? It is a screenshot of @Niklas in Stockholm 's [form from his question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8463209/how-to-make-a-field-conditionally-optional-in-wtforms).

Thank you! 
[image]

Comment: can you show the template code?

Comment: @v1k45 I have edited to include the template! thanks

Comment: Are you returning form A or Additional? I tried using the most basic Jinja template with Flask-Bootstrap and it seemed to work for me. Perhaps something is wrong with your CSS.

Comment: I'm returning form A @Connie

Comment: migrate to https://github.com/helloflask/bootstrap-flask

Answer (score 3):

Since your form class `A` is calling class `Additional` as a `FormField` and only adding `submit` to the field, i added the `submit` button the `Additional` form itself and then called it in the view.

In the template, use

```
{{ wtf.quick_form(form, form_type="inline") }}
```

It outputs the page like this:
[image]

The form_type argument adds the `.form-inline` to the class attribute.

This is just a hack, surely your form will have more inputs than this, for that, you'll be writing the whole form template yourself.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that `{{ wtf.quick_form(form) }}` is calling `wtf.form_field()` on your `FieldList` `additional` in `A` instead of calling it on `additional`'s subfields. Because of this, I don't think you will be able to use `wtf.quick_form()` on your particular form.

Instead, try templating your form like this:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% import "bootstrap/wtf.html" as wtf %}

{% block title %}Grants - Find Grant{% endblock %}

{% block page_content %}
<div class="page-header">
    <h1>Specify</h1>
</div>
<div class="col-md-4">
    <form class="form form-horizontal" method="post" role="form">
        {{ form.hidden_tag() }}
        {{ wtf.form_errors(form, hiddens="only") }}

        {% for subfield in form.additional %}
            {{ wtf.form_field(subfield) }}
        {% endfor %}
        {{ wtf.form_field(form.submit) }}
    </form>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

You can read more about `wtf.form_field()` on the Flask-Bootstrap [documentation](http://pythonhosted.org/Flask-Bootstrap/forms.html) site.