# In Python Flask WTForms, how to create a dependency over another field

Tags: python, flask, flask-wtforms, wtforms

I've a `source` field:

```
source = SelectField("Source", choices=[
                   ('option1', 'option1'),
                   ('option2', 'option2'),
                   ('option3', 'option3'),
               validators=[InputRequired()])
```

Then an `uri` field which requires a different regex based on the above:

```
uri = StringField('URI', Regexp(regex=r'regex1'))
```

Eg. if `option1` is selected regex will be `regex1`, if `option2` `regex2`, and so on.

What would be the proper way to implement it with WTForms?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make a field conditionally optional in WTForms?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8463209/how-to-make-a-field-conditionally-optional-in-wtforms)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This functionality doesn't exist in WTForms. You'll have to tool this yourself. This quickly gets nontrivial, depending on your specific application logic/needs.

One way would be to have client-side JS send requests to a view that dynamically generates a new form, adding on the subsequent sections of the form based on inputs. For example, your fields could have an `onChange` or `onBlur` function that sends the inputs to a view that returns a new form with the next set of fields added on.

Another way to go about this would be with some clever form rendering, CSS and JS. For example, the form would be rendered with all possible fields, but the fields will be hidden and revealed conditionally based on previous selections through via JS/CSS. One concern with this method is that validation becomes complicated.

There are a few [writeups](https://jacobian.org/writing/dynamic-form-generation/) out there on how this is accomplished with Django Forms, but not WTForms. Though, the same concepts should be readily applicable to WTForms.

Related docs: [dynamic form composition](https://wtforms.readthedocs.io/en/stable/specific_problems.html#dynamic-form-composition).