# How to make at least one of two FormFields in WTForms required?

Tags: flask, flask-wtforms, wtforms

I have a form that includes two FormFields with addresses. I want to ensure that at least one of those two is filled out properly. If I make all the relevant fields of the child forms required when only one of them is being filled out it will always fail validation.

```py
class AddressForm(FlaskForm):
    firstname = StringField('Vorname', validators=[InputRequired())
    lastname  = StringField('Nachname', validators=[InputRequired())
    ...

class Registration(FlaskForm):
    use_address_1 = RadioField('use existing address', default='Yes') # which address should be used
    address1      = FormField(AddressForm) # first address e.g. a pre-filled one
    address2      = FormField(AddressForm) # second address if use_address_1 is False
    ...
```

What would be the best practise to implement this in (Flask-)WTForms? Ideally it would be something that could be implemented to the parentclass AddressForm so it would look for the existence of use_address_1 or a parentform with a second address.

Comment: I solved a similar issue with JavaScript :-/

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to make a field conditionally optional in WTForms?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8463209/how-to-make-a-field-conditionally-optional-in-wtforms)

Comment: @pjcunningham It just mighht. I'll have a look at it and see if I can use it for my case. Thanks.