# password fields in wtform do not populate correctly

Tags: flask-wtforms, wtforms

I've got the Settings page where users can change their data (including the password). They should be able to change some data without providing the password everytime. But it looks like the `PasswordField` is not populated correctly and I cannot figure out where to look for a problem. I open the settings page and if I want to change anything in the form I receive the "Passwords must match" error everytime. After debugging I can see that the `password_change` has the correct value but the `password_confirm` is empty. I need to manually provide `password_confirm` value every time. It shouldn't be required. How do wtforms populate the PasswordField and why that doesn't work?

> view.py

```
else:  # GET
    form = UserEditForm(obj=acc)
    return render_template('account/view.html', account=acc, form=form)
```

```
class UserEditForm(Form):
    name = StringField('Account name', [DataOptional(), validators.Length(min=3, max=64)])
    email = StringField('Email address', [
        IgnoreUnchanged(),
        validators.Length(min=3, max=254),
        validators.Email(message='Must be a valid email address'),
        EmailAvailable(),
        validators.EqualTo('email_confirm', message='Email confirmation must match'),
    ])
    email_confirm = StringField('Confirm email address')
    password_change = PasswordField('Change password', [
        validators.EqualTo('password_confirm', message='Passwords must match'),
    ])
    password_confirm = PasswordField('Confirm password')
```

```
<div class="form__question">
    {{ render_field(form.password_change, placeholder="********") }}
</div>
<div class="form__question">
    {{ render_field(form.password_confirm, placeholder="********") }}
</div>
```

Comment: the object 'acc' you are sending to your class UserEditForm, is it the case that it has a field named 'password_change' but not a field named 'password_confirm"? If not, what is the name of the field in your object which has your password value?

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this, making the password field optional, and then only require the password_confirm field if data exist in the password_change field

```
password_change = PasswordField(
    'password',
    validators=[DataOptional(), validators.Length(min=6, max=255)]
)
password_confirm = PasswordField(
    'Repeat password',
    validators=[
        RequiredIf('password_change'),
        EqualTo('password_change', message='Passwords must match.')
    ]
)
```

##### create a validator class for RequiredIf

##### source -> [How to make a field conditionally optional in WTForms?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8463209/how-to-make-a-field-conditionally-optional-in-wtforms)

```
class RequiredIf(InputRequired):
    # a validator which makes a field required if
    # another field is set and has a truthy value

    def __init__(self, other_field_name, *args, **kwargs):
        self.other_field_name = other_field_name
        super(RequiredIf, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def __call__(self, form, field):
        other_field = form._fields.get(self.other_field_name)
        if other_field is None:
            raise Exception('no field named "%s" in form' % self.other_field_name)
        if bool(other_field.data):
            super(RequiredIf, self).__call__(form, field)
```