# WTForms Render FieldList With Zero Entries

Tags: python, flask, wtforms, flask-wtforms

Using the example from the WTForms documentation:

```
class IMForm(Form):
    protocol = SelectField(choices=[('aim', 'AIM'), ('msn', 'MSN')])
    username = StringField()

class ContactForm(Form):
    first_name  = StringField()
    last_name   = StringField()
    im_accounts = FieldList(FormField(IMForm))
```

I am looking to make an IMForm username a required field, but maintain the ability to provide 0..n im_accounts.

Is it possible to render the protocol and username fields in a Flask template without using min_entries=1 or appending an entry, thus triggering the username requirement error if no IM accounts are submitted?

Comment: [I believe you are looking for custom validators.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8445332/can-wtforms-custom-validator-make-a-field-optional)

Comment: The answer your question is yes. Just render it exactly how you said it, and it will work. There's nothing special to do.